# Pyzmq's eventloop.future context with 'inproc' in worker threads

Tags: multithreading, async-await, tornado, pyzmq, inproc

Part of my application consists of a main thread and a couple of worker threads that send their results to the main thread using `pyzmq` sockets. The main thread is running a `tornado IOloop` and uses `async` functions to read the incoming data on a variety of socket types created using a `future.context`.

For performance reasons I would like to use the `inproc` protocol. However `inproc` only works when the main thread and the worker threads share the identical context. This on the other hand would require that each worker thread needs to run a `tornado IOloop`, which I think is bit a overkill for simple workers.

A minimal example to illustrate the problem:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

import zmq
from zmq.eventloop.future import Context as FutureContext
import tornado.ioloop

def worker(ctx):
    socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    socket.bind('inproc://worker')

    while True:
        # Do some work
        time.sleep(2)
        socket.send_pyobj("Work done")

async def mainLoop(ctx):
    socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
    socket.connect('inproc://worker')

    while True:
        #print(socket.recv_pyobj())
        print(await socket.recv_pyobj()) 


normalCtx = zmq.Context()
futureCtx = FutureContext()

t = Thread(target=worker, kwargs=dict(ctx=normalCtx))
t.start()

# wait for bind to be effective
time.sleep(4)

io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
io_loop.spawn_callback(mainLoop, ctx=futureCtx)
io_loop.start()
```

In the example, the `PULL` socket won't receive messages since it is issued on a different context than the worker socket. The example works fine if I use the `normalCtx` in both threads (removing `await`). It also works fine when using TCP as the transport protocol.

The solutions to get it working I found are:

1. Use `normal` context and give up the `async/await`.
2. Use `future` context and run an `ioloop` in each worker.
3. Use TCP as the transport protocol.

My question is if there is a magic trick to get it working with `async/await`, `inproc` and not having to run `ioloops` in the workers, e.g. by accessing the `future` context in a `non-future` way?